# Customize the depth setting in Sonarquebe rule "squid:MaximumInheritanceDepth"

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonarquebe complains that

[image]

**Question**: can can customize the rule setting, say increase the threshold from `5` to `6`?

And more specifically can set the rule to be dynamic depends on which base class is? E.g. the depth of a class extends from XxxModelBase limits to 6, while for other cases, the limits is 4. Is this even doable?

Answer (score 1):

Open the [rule in SonarQube](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AMaximumInheritanceDepth) and you'll see that it can definitely be customised. The `maximum depth` is a parameter that you set when [enabling](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Rules) the rule in the Quality Profile used by this project.

However there's no way to have the rule behave dynamically depending on the class inheritance tree.